# Keep getting Excel and Windows Prompts while working with Interop Services

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

**All of this is being done in VB.NET using the Excel 14.0 Interop Services**

I am at my wits end. I keep getting prompts from windows and excel during the middle of a batch run.

The program i have takes in a workbook with batch records, then runs simulations on each batch record, then writes the results back out to the excel file.

The steps:

1. Open workbook
2. check to see if workbook is already in use by another program.

   1. if it is in use. we try to close the workbook. then we wait for a set amount of time before trying again.
   2. if the workbook is not in use we continue.
3. Get the contents
4. Mark the records as being processed
5. save and close the file.
6. process the records.
7. do the same process above to open the workbook.
8. save the results to the workbook.
9. close the workbook.
10. loop these processes until all the records have been simulated.

Ok the problems that can occur:
Workbook is already in use or two programs are trying to interact with the save workbook at the same time.

Ok now for the problem that i am having.
When the workbook is being interacted with by two programs at the same time. a prompt will show saying the file is currently in use.

another problem that happens that i can't explain is excel will show a prompt saying that the file is now ready to be modified with the options read-write, notify, cancel.

I need to find a way to handle these prompts programmatically.
If any one can point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

Comment: You need to show us some of your code.  Specifically for steps 1 thru 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the prompts from appearing by setting:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
xlApp.DisplayEvents = False
```

But I've not found a way to actually "catch" the prompts and do something useful. I've noticed that often if Interop cannot get hold of a file then it will throw an exception. The exception rarely contains any way to distinguish what the actual error is, but you can sometimes work it out based on what could happen at that point.